# Using Multiple Splice insert with javascript

Tags: javascript

im having problem with multiple usage of splice() method.

```
string= "test"
splitted = string.split('');
splitted.splice(1,0,"ww");
console.log(splitted);
```

so when i use like this output is `(5) ['t', 'ww', 'e', 's', 't']` so all good. but lets assume that i want to use this method multiple times with a different indexes and different string to insert. im looking for somethig like this;

```
string= "test"
splitted = string.split('');
splitted.splice((1,0,"ww"),(2,0,"ss"),(3,0,"dd"));
console.log(splitted);
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

Splice mutates the original object and returns the removed values.
so calling it multiple times on the variable `splitted` does the trick you desire.

```js
string= "test"
splitted = string.split('');
splitted.splice(1,0,"ww")
splitted.splice(2,0,"ss")
splitted.splice(3,0,"dd")

console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: i dont have to mutate it, is there any other method that i can use with more clear syntax to achieve my final result ?

Comment: Mutating is just modifying in place without returning a new object that represents the result, so it rather returns what has been removed. I can not think of a syntax that is "more clear" to achieve this behavior. There could be a better syntax, but only for specific use cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do multiple operations you have to call splice multiple times. Either you code it to be called multiple times or you use an array and loop to call it multiple times.

```js
const string = "test"
const splitted = string.split('');

const updates = [
  [1, 0, "ww"],
  [2, 0, "ss"],
  [3, 0, "dd"]
];

updates.forEach(update => splitted.splice(...update));

console.log(splitted);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function if you want to make the content of that slice dynamically. and make the changes as parameter

```
function split(start, deleteCount , input) {
    string= "test"
    splitted = string.split('');
    splitted.splice(start, deleteCount , input);
    console.log(splitted)    
}

split(1,0,'ww')
split(2,0,'ss')
split(3,0,'dd')
```

or if you want make slice multiple time at once, you can make content of slice as an array

```
function split(modData) {
    for(let val of modData) {
        string= "test"
        splitted = string.split('');
        splitted.splice(...val);
        console.log(splitted)  
    }
}

const data = [
   [1, 0, "ww"],
   [2, 0, "ss"],
   [3, 0, "dd"]
]

split(data)
```